# Ajax PUT REST request to update database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, jersey

I have trouble calling my REST api inside javascript, I receive Bad Request or Unsupported Media Type depending of my test...

My Servlet:

```
   /**
    * Update an existing frame
    * 
    * @param id the id of the <frameConfig> to update
    * @param frameConfig the updated data
    * @return the Updated <frameConfig>
    */
   @Path("/frame/{id}/")
   @PUT
   @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public Response updateFrame(@PathParam("id") String id, final FrameConfig frameConfig) {

      String idOfTheUpdatedFrame = FrameService.getInstance().updateFrame(id, frameConfig);
      URI uri = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder().path(idOfTheUpdatedFrame).build();

      return Response.ok(uri).build();
   }
```

My javascript:

```
            $.ajax({ 
                headers: { 
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
                },
                   type: "PUT",
                   dataType: "json",
                   url: "http://localhost:8080/densite-simulator-WebApp/rest/frames/frame/" + configToUpdate[0].id,
                   data: configToUpdate[0],
                   success: function(data){        
                     alert(data);
                   }
                });
```

Does the datatype in the Ajax call is for the retrieved data after the call success or is it the type of the data that is sent?

Answer (score 0):

`datatype` property is used for the expected returned data format of the `response`.  If it is not specified `Javascript` will do its best to guess what type it should be...